# Streamlit state management does not work for text input field

Tags: python, streamlit

The goal is to build a Streamlit app where data is rendered based on the selected group. The user can type the group or use the "next group" button. I have 2 approaches but they both have issues.

## Approach 1

```py
import streamlit as st

groups = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

group_id = st.text_input(f'Group (1-{len(groups)}):', value=1, key='selected_group')

selected_group = int(st.session_state["selected_group"])
st.text(selected_group)

if st.button('Next group'):
    st.session_state['selected_group'] += 1
```

There is an error when pressing pressing the 'next' button:

> StreamlitAPIException: st.session_state.selected_group cannot be modified after the widget with key selected_group is instantiated.

## Approach 2

```py
import streamlit as st

groups = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

st.session_state["selected_group"] = st.session_state.get("selected_group", 1)

group_id = st.text_input(f'Group (1-{len(groups)}):', value=st.session_state["selected_group"])
st.session_state["selected_group"] = int(group_id)
selected_group = int(st.session_state["selected_group"])
st.text(selected_group)

if st.button('Next group'):
    st.session_state['selected_group'] = selected_group + 1
    st.experimental_rerun()
```

Here the 'next' button works correctly. However there's a weird behavior. The first time in the app I input a custom group, it works. The second time:

- I insert a group in the input and press enter
- Nothing happens
- The group is still the previous one
- I insert the new group again
- This time it works

Answer (score 0):

I just use your approach 1 code and revised it.

Create a session variable with key `gnum`. This is used to track the current value of group_id. If user inputs a number, this number will be stored in gnum. If user presses the button, we just increment the gnum by 1 and the current value is updated. Since the value of input is gnum, the value that will appear in the input is updated after calling rerun().

```py
import streamlit as st

groups = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

if 'gnum' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.gnum = 1

group_id = st.text_input(
    f'Group (1-{len(groups)}):',
    value=st.session_state.gnum,
    key='selected_group'
)

selected_group = group_id
st.text(selected_group)

if st.button('Next group'):
    st.session_state['gnum'] = int(group_id) + 1
    st.rerun()  # to see the current value of gnum in the text input
```